# WP плагин похожие записи - подскажите подходящий

Tags: wordpress

Требования:

чтобы похожие записи можно было переименовать во что-угодно(похожие документы, например)
чтобы можно было произвольно добавлять с админки их список
чтобы автоматически не добавлялись сами(без ручного добавления)

Подскажите плагин который может удовлетворить этим требованиям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Подскажите плагин который может удовлетворить этим требованиям.

Почти во всех стандартных это есть.

А есть и такие: https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-connector/screenshots/